A father seeks revenge on a gang who shot his family
I have seen many movies when I was young, none of which I remember the titles. This one is still stuck in my memory.
This thriller (or drama) movie is about a good father who lost his son because someone shot him at the gas station (I don't remember why).  He decides to seek revenge himself on the person who killed his son (who belonged to a gang). He manages to kill him, but apparently the gang wanted revenge.
They go after the father's family, and shoot them all. 
He goes back to kill the gang again, he kills them all besides one who will tell him something similar to 'Look at you. You're like us now'.
Seen this well-produced american movie after 2006.

Sounds like Death Sentence from 2007. From Wiki:

Nick Hume (Kevin Bacon) is husband to Helen (Kelly Preston), and father of two boys, Brendan (Stuart Lafferty) and Lucas (Jordan Garrett). After Brendan's hockey game, Nick and Brendan drive home, talking about the latter's potential future as a professional hockey player. They make a quick stop at a gas station in a very bad part of town. During an ostensible robbery of the gas station, Joe Darley (Matt O'Leary), a new initiate and younger brother to the gang leader, slices Brendan's throat open with a machete. Nick attempts to ambush the thugs, managing to pull off Joe's mask and see his face, but Joe escapes, only to be hit by a car. Nick rushes Brendan to the hospital, but his son dies from major blood loss.

Nick finds the man who killed his son and stabs him. The gang, seeking revenge, track down his family and shoot them. Nick, in retaliation, hunts them down. He kills them all and in the end, the gang leader tells him: "Look at you. You look like one of us." Here's the trailer:




Apologies to the Bacon, but Death Wish was better.

Yeah, that was one of the worst Kevin Bacon movies I've seen.
